# Add form fields dynamically populated dropdown list with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to make 3 form fields (a dropdown list dynamically populated by a .php script and 2 text fields) and also with a button add 3 more and 3 more and so on (as user clicks the button) I have tried several ways but nothing seems to work for me. (I'm noob in JS, AJAX, jQuery so I mostly tried scripts I've found on the internet).
Here's the code of these form fields:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="results.php">
 <div id="itemRows">
    <select name="species">
            <option value="">Select Species</option>';
            <?php $sql = "SELECT common FROM species";
            $speciesq = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($speciesq))
{
    echo "<option value=\"" . $row['common'] ."\">" . $row['common'] ."</option>";
}
?> 
</select>
    Number: <input type="text" name="speciesnumber1" size="7" /> Weight: <input type="text" name="speciesweight1" /> <input onClick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="+" />     
    </div></form>
```

and after this form there's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rowNum = 0;
var ddsel = '<select name="species'+rowNum+'>';
var ddopt = '<option value="">Select Species</option>';
var ddselc= '</select>';
function addRow(frm) {
    rowNum ++;
    $.post("getlist.php", function(data) {
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            ddopt += '<option value="'+data[i].value+'">'+data[i].value+'</option>';
        } 
    }, "json");
    var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">'+ddsel+ddopt+ddselc+'Number: <input type="text" name="speciesnumber'+rowNum+'" size="7" value="'+frm.add_qty.value+'"> Weight: <input type="text" name="speciesweight'+rowNum+'" value="'+frm.add_name.value+'"> <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></p>';
    jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
    frm.add_qty.value = '';
    frm.add_name.value = '';
}

function removeRow(rnum) {
    jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
}
</script>
```

getlist.php is a simple script that populates the dropdown list and sends the data:

```
<?php
include("dbcon.php");
$sql = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT common FROM species");
$result = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $result[] = array(
    'value' => $row['common'],
    );
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

So when I click the "+" button (to add the row) nothing happens.

### SOLVED: for those who come here please read also the comments below the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have some code in the wrong spot:

```
var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">'+ddsel+ddopt+ddselc+'Number: <input type="text" name="speciesnumber'+rowNum+'" size="7" value="'+frm.add_qty.value+'"> Weight: <input type="text" name="speciesweight'+rowNum+'" value="'+frm.add_name.value+'"> <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></p>';
jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
frm.add_qty.value = '';
frm.add_name.value = '';
```

needs to be moved into the post return function like this:

```
function addRow(frm) {
    rowNum ++;
    $.post("getlist.php", function(data) {
        var frm = document.getElementById('form1');
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            ddopt += '<option value="'+data[i].value+'">'+data[i].value+'</option>';
        } 
        var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">'+ddsel+ddopt+ddselc+'Number: <input type="text" name="speciesnumber'+rowNum+'" size="7" value="'+frm.add_qty.value+'"> Weight: <input type="text" name="speciesweight'+rowNum+'" value="'+frm.add_name.value+'"> <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></p>';
        jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
        frm.add_qty.value = '';
        frm.add_name.value = '';
    }, "json");
}
```

Comment: @GeorgePtl Does it give an error?  Do you have this live anywhere it can be seen?

Comment: OK... It didn't have the reference to the form.  I've adjusted the code now.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize your form names weren't correct.  Looks like add_qty should be speciesnumber1 and add_name should be speciesweight1?  If you update those, are you ok?