# Add form fields dynamically with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Referring to this post.  [Add form fields dynamically populated dropdown list with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088544/add-form-fields-dynamically-populated-dropdown-list-with-php)  I have used his code but will modify it to fit my needs since I pretty much nothing about javascript.  I have everything working except when you press the + button it never creates more input boxes.  Any help would be great.

This my php file

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("dbconfig.php");
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="addfish.js"></script>
</head>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="results.php">
 <div id="itemRows">
    <select name="species">
            <option value="">Select Species</option>';
            <?php $stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT species FROM fish");
            $stmt->execute();

while($speciesq = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<option value=\"" . $speciesq['species'] ."\">" . $speciesq['species'] ."</option>";
}
?> 
</select>
    Number: <input type="text" name="speciesnumber1" size="7" /> Weight: <input type="text" name="speciesweight1" /> <input onClick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="+" />     
    </div></form>


</html>
```

My addfish.js file

```
var rowNum = 0;
var ddsel = '<select name="species'+rowNum+'>';
var ddopt = '<option value="">Select Species</option>';
var ddselc= '</select>';
;
function addRow(frm) {
    rowNum ++;
    $.post("getlist.php", function(data) {
        var frm = document.getElementById('form1')
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            ddopt += '<option value="'+data[i].value+'">'+data[i].value+'</option>';
        } 
        var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">'+ddsel+ddopt+ddselc+'Number: <input type="text" name="speciesnumber'+rowNum+'" size="7" value="'+frm.speciesnumber1.value+'"> Weight: <input type="text" name="speciesweight'+rowNum+'" value="'+frm.speciesweight.value+'"> <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></p>';
        jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
        frm.add_qty.value = '';
        frm.add_name.value = '';
    }, "json");
}
function removeRow(rnum) {
    jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
}
```

This is my getlist.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include("dbconfig.php");
$stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT species FROM fish");
$stmt->execute();
$result = array();
while ($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   $result[] = array(
    'value' => $rows['species'],
    );
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: Try opening the developer tools of your browser and take a look at the JavaScript console. You will find many debug information there.

If they won't help you try post them. This will help us a lot.

Comment: Javascript console says this

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined addfish.js:13
(anonymous function) addfish.js:13
j jquery.min.js:2
k.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
x jquery.min.js:4
b

Comment: OK i found it
value="'+frm.speciesweight.value+'" name was wrong should be value="'+frm.speciesweight1.value+'"  Thanks for the comments

Comment: So always look up in the developer tools. They give you helpful information just like the hint that "speciesweight" has no attribute "value". Reading debug information is a little bit confusing at the beginning but it helps you a lot!

Comment: Yes, thank you Daniel.  Still new at this and was unaware of the javascript console.  Thank you for pointing me there!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using jQuery, but I don't see where you include this library. Try to put this code before include addfish.js in header :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add rows with this fields dynamically I suggest you make a row which is the original row:

```
<div class="rows" data-rows="1">
    <div class="row row-first">
       <select name="row[0][select_name]">
          <option value="1">Some value</option>
       </select>

       <input type="text" name="row[0][text_name]" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#add_row').on('click', function(){
        var row = $('.row-first').clone(); // Clone the first row
        var rows = parseInt($('.rows').attr('data-rows'));
        rows++;
        $('.rows').attr('data-rows', rows);

        row.removeClass('row-first'); // Prevent multiple rows cloning

        $(row).find('[name]').each(function(){
              var name = $(this).attr('name');
              name = name.replace(/\[[0-9+]\]/, '[' + rows + ']');
              $(this).attr('name', name);
              $(this).val("").change(); // Null the select
        });

       $('.rows').append(row);
    });
</script>
```

So what you do is clone the first row and remove the class, which you search. Increment the rows count and replace all names in you row with the new row number e.g. row[0][name] becomes row[1][name], and append the row.

Also when you edit the rows you MUST put set the data-rows to the exact number. You can do it like **count($myRows)**. And when you write the remove row function DO NOT REMOVE the first row.

Hope it hepls.

Answer (score 0):

```
// You can use this 

var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">'+ddsel+ddopt+ddselc+'Number: <input type="text" name="speciesnumber'+rowNum+'" size="7" value="'+$($(frm).find('input[name="speciesnumber1"]')[0]).val()+'"> Weight: <input type="text" name="speciesweight'+rowNum+'" value="'+$($(frm).find('input[name="speciesnumber1"]')[0]).val()+'"> <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></p>';
            jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
```